# What is the word "who"?

Tags: pronouns, adverbs, questions, parts-of-speech

Is the word "who" an adverb? If not, what is it? If it is an adverb, what type of adverb is it?

Answer (score 10):

As [Jon Purdy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6175/what-is-the-word-who/6177#6177) said, it can be an *interrogative pronoun*:

> **Who** are you?

It can also be a *relative pronoun*:

> I'm the one **who** was driving.

Answer (score 3):

It's an [interrogative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word).